# S3 access denied when trying to run aws cli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli, validationerror, aws-appsync

using the AWS CLI I'm trying to run

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name FullstackLambda --template-url https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awsappsync/resources/lambda/LambdaCFTemplate.yam --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region us-west-2
```

but I get the error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: S3 error: Access Denied
```

I have already set my credential with

```
aws configure
```

PS I got the create-stack command from the AppSync docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally skipped **l** letter at the end of template file name:

LambdaCFTemplate.yam -> LambdaCFTemplate.yam**l**

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the S3 URL is correct. But since this is a 403, I doubt it's the case.

Yours could result from a few different scenarios.

1.If both APIs and IAM user are MFA protected, you have to generate temporary credentials using `aws sts get-session-token` and use it

2.Use a role to provide cloudformation read access to the template object in S3. First create a IAM role with read access to S3. Then create a parameter like below and ref it in resource properties **IamInstanceProfile** block

```
  "InstanceProfile":{  
     "Description":"Instance Profile Name",
     "Type":"String",
     "Default":"iam-test-role"
  }
```